# stack of a function containing an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, compiler-construction

I got asked an interesting question regarding the call stack of a function containing an async function.

Here is an example:

```
function test(a)
{
    call_server(“www.awebsite.com/api”, a, callback);//async
}
```

What does the call stack look like? My understanding is:
push(test)
push(a)
push(call_server)

and then: 
pop(call_server)
pop(a)
pop(test)

But my question is where is the position of the callback of "call_server". When does it get triggered and get allocated space in stack.

Thanks

Comment: What is the programming language you use? Where call_server function is declared?

Comment: What do  you mean by "async function"?  As in C#?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is javascript. Async function means the function is run asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Given the scant information and by observation:

1. `callback` is pushed on the stack frame of `function test` to be passed to the `call_server` function or it is being passed in a register. This is depending on the calling convention.
2. `callback` is neither defined in scope of `function test` or passed into the function so I assume it is defined outside.
3. It is likely that `callback` is a pointer or a reference of some kind to the callback function definition.
4. It is reasonable to think, sight unseen, that `call_server` captures the reference or pointer to `callback` in it's async thread local storage or a keyed memory location.
5. When the async call is completed then it calls invokes the `callback` function in the async stack frame context.
6. Finally, `callback`, which is likely a function, establishes it's own stack frame to do whatever it does.

Comment: This sounds like an implementation of "fork".   Are you claiming that is the same as a C# async function?

Comment: @IraBaxter OP did not state anything about C# analogy. I was answering his question(s).